# Display multiple lists at once in WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, wpf-controls

Let's say I have an indefinite amount of Branch objects and each one has a List with the employees of that branch. 
I now want to list all employees of all branches grouped by their respective branch in one ListView element.
The only solution I come up with is to run through all branches, pull their employees and put them in a separate list which I then use as the ListView's ItemsSource. Is there an easier and/or more effective way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for when you say "easier" then adding all the desired items to the list? Depending on what your program looks like you should be able to assign the ItemSource to a custom object that implements IEnumerable and have it automatically enumerate multiple lists at once. But I am not sure if that is "easier"

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you have a list of an object, and it has a other list in its properties. And you need sum of all inner lists.

See [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use it like

```
MyList.SelectMany(item=>item.OtherLists);
```

it gives you sum of all OtherList's elements.

For grouping, see [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx)

and you can use it like that

```
Innerlist.GroupBy(item=>item.Id)
```

you should use GroupBy first, SelectMany later, based on your question, something like

```
Branches.GroupBy(branch=>branch.Name).SelectMany(item=>item.Employees)
```

and you can put them in a list(and bind them), or just set the ItemsSource.